# Sansevieria falling back to the wild form via leaf cuttings but not via micropropagation

Tags: botany, cloning

I have heard that when you propagate Sansevieria via leaf cuttings, you get the wild form again. But if you use only meristem tissue, you can propagate the multicolored cultivated forms. What would be a possible explanation for this phenomenon?

Comment: This *might* be a better fit for [gardening.se].

Comment: A source for the claim would be a big help.